# QUnit and urlencode

Tags: urlencode, qunit

I'm trying to test a utility method I have that creates urlencoded query strings. It somehow decodes "expected" in to: ?foo=foo val&bar=bar&val ... so it's decoding the urlencoding!

```
test("test make_params properly url encodes", function() {
    var o = {"foo":'foo val',"bar":'bar&val'}; 
    var actual = make_params(o);
    equals('?foo=foo+val&bar=bar%26val', actual, "Expected urlencoded string built to be" + '?foo=foo+val&bar=bar%26val');
});
```

Results in:
   1. Expected urlencoded string built to be?foo=foo+val&bar=bar%26val, expected: 
"**?foo=foo val&bar=bar&val**" result: "?foo=foo+val&bar=bar%26val", diff: "?foo=foo val&bar=bar&val" "?foo=foo+val&bar=bar%26val"

Is this a bug in qunit or am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One minor issue: equals expect the actual value as the first argument, the expected as the second. And equals is now deprecated in [favor of equal](http://docs.jquery.com/QUnit/equal).

Based on that its likely that the test works fine, but the make_params method doesn't actually encode anything.